# Group Mailbox Monitoring in Microsoft Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, mailbox

I would like to be able to determine who read an email in one of my group mailboxes. Is there any area in Outlook that will tell me the user, time, and date of the incoming message being marked as read?

Answer (score 0):

**Who has read the message in a shared mailbox?**

According to http://www.msoutlook.info/question/314

"You cannot directly tell who has read the message already but you can easily create a system for it with categories."

There is a discussion here [Accountability for emails marked as read in shared inbox (Outlook 2007)](https://superuser.com/questions/366456/accountability-for-emails-marked-as-read-in-shared-inbox-outlook-2007)